How do I remove a NO_PUBKEY GPG Error?
sudo apt update
[sudo] password for user:
...               
Get:7 https://repositories.intel.com/gpu/ubuntu jammy InRelease [15.4 kB]      
Err:7 https://repositories.intel.com/gpu/ubuntu jammy InRelease                
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 28DA432DAAC8BAEA
...
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
1562 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
...
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://repositories.intel.com/gpu/ubuntu jammy InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 28DA432DAAC8BAEA
W: Failed to fetch https://repositories.intel.com/gpu/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 28DA432DAAC8BAEA
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

I want to quickly remove the public key that is causing this error.
GPG error: https://repositories.intel.com/gpu/ubuntu jammy InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 28DA432DAAC8BAEA

apt-key remove isn't working.

The key error is merely a symptom. The underlying cause is that the repository is no longer maintained.
Removing the key won't accomplish anything. It's already a NO_PUBKEY error.
Step 1: Review the software that you installed from that dead repository. See if there are better options available elsewhere.
Step 2: Delete the repository from your apt sources. You cannot use it anymore.

How do I find the repository to delete? The only info from the error is repositories.intel.com/gpu/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease and NO_PUBKEY 28DA432DAAC8BAEA

Huh? Did your system come pre-installed with Ubuntu? You never any installed non-Ubuntu software for your GPU?
